# simple keyboard event handler in D

Tags: linux, windows, events, d, keypress

I am trying to make a simple keypress handler that I can recycle into any program I'd like to make in D. In my search I can only really find information on how to do this in C, namely by using getch() to read characters from the command line input buffer. But I don't neccessarily want to run a program on the command line. Much like every other program in existence. I've been looking everywhere for this, even on Dlang.org , and haven't found a satisfactory answer yet.

In my specific case I'm trying to make a simple game as a project to help me learn D and I realized that I needed keypress handling so I could, at the very least, navigate menus I'd create in a more natural way so I could properly test my game.

I would eventually like this system to be usable on both windows and linux interchangably, probably just by detecting the operating system the program is running on at launch and then choosing the right code to run to make it all work. But that will come later. Right now i just want to know how to build a simple Keypress event handler that can trigger a function or method or whatever I want as soon as I press the key and have it work in a windows environment.

Comment: Do you want a text or graphical environment? For text, my terminal.d does it and for graphical, my simpledisplay.d will get you started. I'd have to write an example though, and I'm in the middle of something else right now, but I can later tonight or maybe tomorrow.

Comment: And you think this person knows where your code is, Adam? :) Shoopdeboop, the code Adam mentioned above can be found here: https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd

Comment: i'm famous, yo :P the code come up quickly on a web search! But the example is needed to get started and there's ones in my book, and on my documentation site, but those are harder to use! But if you can let me know a few more details, I can write up more details as an answer.

Comment: I'll take more of a look through your code, maybe I can use it to figure out how to build my own, simpler, function or wrapper or something. Mainly I want to learn how to build a tool myself first so I don't use them as crutches and never learn.

Comment: The graphical environment is actually easier to do cross-platform input on (just because the Unix terminal is AN ENORMOUS PAIN IN THE BUTT, things get sent to you as a series of bizarre varying byte sequences in the input stream), though the text one has a simpler hello world. That said though, you can do basic letter key input pretty reliably in like ~30 lines of setup code even on terminal. On Windows, it is quite a bit simpler, the operating system has a sane API, though you should know its quirks too (like it is painfully slow if you don't buffer the console output properly and can flickr)